# Allocating array vs initializing a pointer

Tags: c++, c, initialization, header-files

I have a structure that has an array.

```
struct Page_Directory {
public:
    int numEntries;
    int nextDirPage;
    int [] array;
};
```

However, I always want this array to be of certain length, so that the size of this structure is always 4 + 4 + 100*4 bytes.

I don't want to have a structure declaration like following:

```
struct Page_Directory {
public:
    int numEntries;
    int nextDirPage;
    int *array;
};
```

since size of this structure is 4 + 4 + 4 = 12 bytes (even if I allocate memory to entries by using `new` or `malloc`).

Now, how do I achieve this? I can't put a declaration like the first one in header file, you don't put array size details in the header file, only what each member's type.

Comment: "you don't put array size details in the header file, only what each member's type." why not?

Comment: Do you want to guarantee a certain size in bytes, or a certain number of elements in the array (note that the size of `int` may vary for different platforms)?

Comment: @jogojapan: I want to guarantee that there 2+100 integers in the structure.

Comment: Is this legal...?
`int [] array ;`

Comment: Note that `int [] array;` is *not* allowed by C++ (though gcc/g++ allows it as an extension).

Comment: He probably meant `int array[]`, ie a flexible array member, which is perfectly fine in C since C99.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you always want the array to have a certain size then there is no way around
declaring it with a certain size:

```
struct Page_Directory {
public:
    int numEntries;
    int nextDirPage;
    int array[100];
};
```

Comment: What's puzzling me is why the OP is reluctant to do this. Seems the **obvious** answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
<datatype> [] <array_name> ;
```

is not allowed in C++

You can try this also ...

```
struct Page_Directory {
public:
    int numEntries;
    int nextDirPage;
    static int const size=100;
    int  array[size];
};
```